# Bash script - How to loop through rows in a CSV file

Tags: bash, shell, loops, csv, if-statement

I am working with a huge CSV file (`filename.csv`) that contains a single column. From column 1, I wanted to read current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is `greater` OR `equal`, continue comparing and if the value of the current cell is `smaller` than the previous row - divide the value of the current cell by the value of the previous cell and exit by printing the value of the division. For example from the following example: i wanted my `bash` script to divide 327 by 340 and print 0.961765 to the console and exit.

```
338
338
339
340
327
301
299
284
284
283
283
283
282
282
282
283
```

I tried it with the following awk and it works perfectly fine.

`awk '$1 < val {print $1/val; exit} {val=$1}' filename.csv`

However, since i want to include around 7 conditional statements (`if-else`'s), I wanted to do it with a bit cleaner bash script and here is my approach. I am not that used to awk to be honest and that's why i prefer to use bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

FileName="filename.csv"
# Test when to stop looping
STOP=1

# to find the number of columns
NumCol=`sed 's/[^,]//g' $FileName | wc -c`; let "NumCol+=1"

# Loop until the current cell is less than the count+1

while [ "$STOP" -lt "$NumCol" ]; do

        cat $FileName | cut -d, -f$STOP
        let "STOP+=1"
done
```

How can we loop through the values and add conditional statements?

PS: the criteria for my if-else statement is (if the value (`$1/val`) is >=0.85 and <=0.9, print A, else if the value (`$1/val`) is >=0.7 and <=0.8, print B, if the value (`$1/val`) is >=0.5 and <=0.6 print C otherwise print D).

Comment: What is wrong with `awk`'s `if-else`s?

Comment: Well, there is `if` and even `else` in awk, too, and you don't even need `fi`.

Comment: nothing is wrong with awk but i am not used to it and that's why. Thanks.

Comment: What is the criteria you want to apply in if-then-else?

Comment: @george-vasiliou, I have included that to the question now. thank you.

Comment: You say `if the value is 0.9, print A`. Does this refer to the value of `$1/val` ?

Comment: @george-vasiliou, yes that's what i meant.

Comment: OK.. One more question : The value of 0.9 is a rounded value? The result 0.961765  should print "A" or should print "D"?

Comment: I am sorry George, it should not be rounded dear. Let's take the first two values after the decimal.

Comment: In my solution i do not make "mathematical" rounding. I just take the first three chars from the `$1/val` result using substring function of awk. So if `$1/val` = `0.961765` with `substr` we get `0.9` . If you want solutions to be adjusted for 0.96 you need to redifine your criteria also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one in GNU awk using `switch`, because I haven't used it in a while:

```
awk '
$1<p { 
    s=sprintf("%.1f",$1/p)
    switch(s) {
    case "0.9":            # if comparing to values ranged [0.9-1.0[ use /0.9/
        print "A"          # ... in which case (no pun) you don't need sprintf
        break
    case "0.8":
        print "B"
        break
    case "0.7":
        print "c"
        break
    default:
        print "D"
    }
    exit
}
{ p=$1 }' file
D
```

Other awks using `if`:

```
awk '
$1<p { 
#    s=sprintf("%.1f",$1/p)  # s is not rounded anymore
    s=$1/p                  
#    if(s==0.9)              # if you want rounding, 
#        print "A"           # uncomment and edit all ifs to resemble
    if(s~/0.9/) 
        print "A"
    else if(s~/0.8/) 
        print "B"
    else if(s~/0.7/) 
        print "c"
    else
        print "D"
    exit
}
{ p=$1 }' file
D
```

Comment: Why 6 A's? I want to print only one value and then exit.

Comment: You can probably move the exit outside of switch instead having exit in each case.

Comment: `sprintf` rounds the first value 0.96 to 1.0, hence the D.

Comment: @james-brown, there is this error. "`awk: syntax error at source line 4
 context is
     switch(s) >>>  { <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 4
awk: syntax error at source line 5`"

Comment: It's for GNU awk only. Which awk are you using?

Comment: I am using awk on Mac.

Comment: Try the latter with `if`s.

Comment: This is a nice awk case tutorial. I had not worked with switch/case in awk before. Very nice.

Comment: `switch`is ok but you can only compare to `"0.9"` or `/0.9/` so rounding must be done outside of it.

Comment: Why is it printing out D? Shouldn't it print out A like in your first answer James?

Comment: (see 3rd comment) First I used 0.9 from 0.96 which caused A. Then you mentioned rounding so I rounded 0.96 which is 1.0, ie. D.

Comment: oh, I am sorry James, it should not be rounded dear. Let's take the first two values after the decimal. (for example 0.96).

Comment: So anything starting with 0.9 causes A, anything starting with 0.8 bauses B? Gimme a sec.

Comment: Actually, i wanted it be for  a value >=0.85 and a value <=0.9 to be A. But i will work on that

Comment: OK, then the `if`s should be `if(s>=0.85 && s<=0.9)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative approach,based on previous input data describing comparison of `$1/val` with fixed numbers `0.9` , `0.7` and `0.6`.
This solution will not work with ranges like `($1/val) >=0.85 and <=0.9` as clarified later.

```
awk 'BEGIN{crit[0.9]="A";crit[0.7]="B";crit[0.6]="C"} \
$1 < val{ss=substr($1/val,1,3);if(ss in crit) {print crit[ss]} else {print D};exit}{val=$1}' file
A
```

This technique is based on checking if rounded value `$1/val` belongs to a predefined array loaded with corresponding messages.

Let me expand the code for better understanding:

```
awk 'BEGIN{crit[0.9]="A";crit[0.7]="B";crit[0.6]="C"} \   #Define the criteria array. Your criteria values are used as keys and values are the messages you want to print.
$1 < val{
         ss=substr($1/val,1,3);          #gets the first three chars of the result $1/val
         if(ss in crit) {                #checks if the first three chars is a key of the array crit declared in begin
                         print crit[ss]  #if it is, print it's value
                        } 
          else {
                print D                  #If it is not, print D
                };
          exit
        }
{val=$1}' file
```

Using substr we get the first three chars of the result `$1/val`:
for `$1/val = 0.961765` using `substr($1/val,1,3)` returns `0.9`

If you want to make comparisons based on two decimals like `0.96` then change substr like `substr($1/val,1,4)`.
In this case you need to accordingly provide the correct comparison entries in `crit` array i.e `crit[0.96]="A"`

Comment: That's neat also.

Comment: This is so cool too but what if we want to say a value >=0.85 and a value <=0.9 to be A?

Comment: @Mahsolid And this is why questions need to expressed as clearly as possible! This is a new condition! Anyway, i don't think that my solution can work in such case. You probably have to go with James approach. I will let you know if i figure out something cool.